# How can I check the performance of an AMD Radeon GPU on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, performance, amdgpu

I want to check whether my AMD Radeon GPU performs close to the manufacturer's indicated performance.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install the command line utility "radeontop" to check the status of radeon graphics cards. You can install it using `sudo apt install radeontop` and run it using `sudo radeontop`

Edit, removed parts that somebody removed from question.

Comment: There was a lot of questions. The main question was about the GPU. I managed to run radeontop. I  am not sure as yet which of the indicators to look at. I ll ask a question on this if I cant figure out. Thx a lot for taking the time.

Comment: Just FYI the question has been edited to make it suitable for the format of the site. You may feel like editing your answer (but it's fine if you don't).

Comment: Thats actually a good idea zanna, ill do that.

Comment: How cool is this... Terminal based GPU monitoring app. I'm impressed!